# compare 2 csv files on multiple columns and replace one column with column from another file

Tags: linux, awk, csv

I have to compare 2 files `file a` and `file b` with the same columns but are randomly placed in 2 files like compare column values
`account`, `code`, `date`, `type`, `pc`, `vol` and `bs` and if a match is found for any row then replace the column 1 `account` in `file a`
with `account1` from `file b` and display all the non matched records from `file a` . the output `file c` should look like below

I don't have any background in linux, after going through the online forums I got a slight idea that this can be done via AWK but I am not that familiar with awk. please help. The comparison need to be done in linux environment

by randomly placed columns I mean is that in the command I should be able give the columns that I can use to match file a with file b (the order of the column will not be the same in both the files). It can be 8 or 10 or 15 columns to match in both the files.

similiar to that account and account1 must not be the first and last column , the command should have ability to pick what column needs to be updated as well

**duplicates processing**
-->if file b has many duplicates for a 1 record in file a then it should update the file b first matched record so that it cannot be used again in the matching
--> if file a has many duplicates and file b has only 1 matched record then the final file c should have only 1 account value get updated rather than updating all the records of matched values of file a

`file a`

```
account,temp1,code,type,date,subtask,pc,toy,vol,bs,sub
6576,WEQR,TYRE,BS,54122022,OBCD,K,BAT,5000,F,SCSC
1234,GFHD,ASDF,BS,21122022,STOP,C,CAT,1000,S,MATH
7654,GHAD,LOPI,CV,9089022,KGAD,G,BSEE,5908,J,IOYU
```

`file b`

```
account,code,date,type,inst,insttype,pc,str,vol,bs,name,xdate,account1
1234,ASDF,21122022,BS,GOLDY,RUB,C,123.1,1000,S,RON,90891234,CCCCC
2761,LOPCS,10122022,BSFD,SLV,STR,C,123.9,1001,B,RON,99999988,DDDDD
0980,RTDF,28822025,JUFG,BRNZ,HIY,C,123.8,2000,S,RON,88881234,EEEEE
```

`file c`

```
account,temp1,code,type,date,subtask,pc,toy,vol,bs,sub
6576,WEQR,TYRE,BS,54122022,OBCD,K,BAT,5000,F,SCSC
CCCCC,GFHD,ASDF,BS,21122022,STOP,C,CAT,1000,S,MATH
7654,GHAD,LOPI,CV,9089022,KGAD,G,BSEE,5908,J,IOYU
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain in more detail what you consider a match? What exactly means "same columns but are randomly placed"? Is `account` always the first column? Is `account1` always the last column? Can there be duplicate values?

Comment: @Bodo i have updated question based on your query

Answer (score 2):

This answer starts with a solution using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), continues with a solution using Miller in conjunction with `csvsql` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), and then finishes off with a solution that only uses `csvsql`.

---

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (`mlr`) to first (left-)join the data from `fileA` with the data in `fileB` on the following named fields:

```
account,code,date,type,pc,vol,bs
```

... and then rename the `account1` field `account` (for the records that have an `account1` field, which will only be the ones that were joined).

We then reorder the fields and remove the ones we don't want in the output.

```bash
mlr --csv \
    join -f fileA -j account,code,date,type,pc,vol,bs --ul then \
    rename account1,account then \
    cut -o -f account,temp1,code,type,date,subtask,pc,toy,vol,bs,sub fileB
```

The output, given the data in the question:

```
account,temp1,code,type,date,subtask,pc,toy,vol,bs,sub
CCCCC,GFHD,ASDF,BS,21122022,STOP,C,CAT,1000,S,MATH
6576,WEQR,TYRE,BS,54122022,OBCD,K,BAT,5000,F,SCSC
7654,GHAD,LOPI,CV,9089022,KGAD,G,BSEE,5908,J,IOYU
```

Note that the order of the fields in the two input files is irrelevant.

If you don't know what fields you may use to join on, you may calculate the common field names separately (unfortunately, Miller can't do a "natural join" operation but must be given an explicit list of field names to join on):

```bash
mlr --csv put -q '
    if (NR == 1) {
        for (k in $*) { @f[k] = 1 }
    } else {
       for (k in @f) {
           is_null($[k]) { unset @f[k] }
       }
    }
   end {
       common_fieldnames = joink(@f,",");
       emit common_fieldnames
   }' fileA fileB
```

For the given data, this outputs the following CSV data set

```
common_fieldnames
"account,code,type,date,pc,vol,bs"
```

To *only* get the comma-delimited list, use options that would generate header-less unquoted CSV output, e.g. `--csv` in combination with `--headerless-csv-output` and `--quote-none`.

---

A totally different approach is to use `csvsql` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to perform a natural left join, then use `mlr` for post-processing the output:

```bash
csvsql --query 'SELECT * FROM "fileA" NATURAL LEFT JOIN "fileB"' fileA fileB |
mlr --csv \
    put 'is_not_null($account1) { $account = $account1 }' then \
    cut -o -f account,temp1,code,type,date,subtask,pc,toy,vol,bs,sub
```

This way, you don't have to care about what fields are common between the two files.

You could even do it all in SQL if you wish:

```bash
csvsql --query '
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp AS SELECT * FROM "fileA" NATURAL LEFT JOIN "fileB";
    UPDATE tmp SET account = account1 WHERE account1 IS NOT NULL;
    SELECT account,temp1,code,type,date,subtask,pc,toy,vol,bs,sub FROM tmp;' fileA fileB
```

Comment: sorry cannot use Miller in my company

Comment: @Shetty That's a problem that I can not solve for you, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=, hdrs_to_check="$*"
col_to_change="account"
col_with_value="account1"

awk -F, -v hdrs_to_check="$hdrs_to_check" \
        -v col_to_change="$col_to_change" \
        -v col_with_value="$col_with_value" '

function make_compound_key(hdrs_2_idx_map) {
    key = ""
    for (i = 1; i <= hdrs_to_check_arr_size; i++) {
        hdr_name = hdrs_to_check_arr[i]
        hdr_idx = hdrs_2_idx_map[hdr_name]
        key = key$hdr_idx","
    }
    return key
}

BEGIN {
    hdrs_to_check_arr_size = split(hdrs_to_check, hdrs_to_check_arr, ",")
}

#Both file headers processing
FNR == 1 {
    #Map file_a and file_b headers to their indexes.
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) {
        if (NR == 1) {
            f_b_hdr_2_idx_map[$i] = i
        } else {
            f_a_hdr_2_idx_map[$i] = i
        }
    }
    next
}

#file_b processing
FNR == NR {
    key = make_compound_key(f_b_hdr_2_idx_map)

    # Duplicate keys are not changing the "account1" value, it is fixed
    # from the first key occurence.
    if (!(key in file_b_dct)) {
        file_b_dct[key] = $f_b_hdr_2_idx_map[col_with_value]
    }

    next
}

#file_a processing
FNR != NR {
    key = make_compound_key(f_a_hdr_2_idx_map)

    # "file_a_updated_dct" is needed to prevent following lines
    # with same "key" be changed. These lines are left unchanged.
    if ((key in file_b_dct) && !(key in file_a_updated_dct)) {
        $f_a_hdr_2_idx_map[col_to_change] = file_b_dct[key]         
        file_a_updated_dct[key]
    }

    print
}
' file_b.txt OFS=, file_a.txt
#' file_b.txt OFS=, file_a.txt | column -s, -t
```

**Usage:**

```
$ ./my_script.sh account code date type pc vol bs
```

Comment: sorry how do i run this on linux environment

Comment: @Shetty paste to a command line and press Enter. Or put this text into shell script, make it executable and run this script.

Comment: sorry for my ignorance , will you be able to tell how does it compare the 7 column values

Comment: @Shetty It compares only `file_a` and `file_b` **account** columns. I assumed this basing on your `file_c` example and only **account** column changing, now I reread your question and see that some other columns should be checked too, but only **account** column's value should be replaced by the **account1** value.

Comment: will you be able to check and provide solution for that?

Comment: @Shetty Check a new solution.